# how to get table's value via spring controller

Tags: spring, jsp

```
<table id="userRelative_list_table" class="tablebox">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>relativeName</th>
            <th>relativeType</th>
            <th>relativeCardNo</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$("#addRow").button().click(function() {
        var insertRow = "<tr>";
        insertRow = insertRow + "<td>" + relativeNameAdd.val() + "</td>";
        insertRow = insertRow + "<td>" + relativeTypeAdd.val() + "</td>";
        insertRow = insertRow + "<td>" + relativeCardNoAdd.val() + "</td>";
        insertRow = insertRow + "<td><a href='#' onclick ='deleteRow(this)'><img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath }/images/remove.png' title='delete'/></a></td>";
        insertRow = insertRow + "</tr>";
        $("#userRelative_list_table > tbody").append(insertRow);
    }
});
```

**now i hava a table ,when i click button that i can add a row append the table. now my problem is coming. how can i get this table'value in spring controller when i submit this table.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit a table. You submit a **form**.

The table should be wrapped in  tags with an action being specified in the form tag as an attribute or via a jquery event handler. The cells in the table need to be  tags for their values to be submitted to a controller in spring.